# Django: how to get value from model in view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view that will conditionally display a breadcrumb trail based on the value of the object's "status" field. This works if I manually set the status value (ex status = "completed"). However, as a newbie, I can't figure out how to retrieve the value?

`status = Project.status` is not working.

Here is the view:

```
class CompanyProjectsDetailView(DetailBreadcrumbMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    queryset = Project.objects.get_with_counted_notes_documents_todos()
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'
    form_class = ProjectStatusForm
    status = Project.status

    if status == "completed":
        @cached_property
        def crumbs(self):
            return [
                ("projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:" + CompanyProjects.list_view_name, )
                 ),
                (f"completed projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:" + CompanyProjects.list_view_name, )
                 ),
            ]
```

Comment: you need the instance of the Class (an object) or a queryset instead of trying to access the class (Project.status)

Comment: Thanks Alvi15. I thought that must be the case. I just haven't been able to figure out  a way to access the instance yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this to work. The key is getting the instance in the crumbs method. I imagine there may be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

The working view:

```
class CompanyProjectsDetailView(DetailBreadcrumbMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    queryset = Project.objects.get_with_counted_notes_documents_todos()
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'
    form_class = ProjectStatusForm
    # pk_url_kwarg = 'project_id'

    @cached_property
    def crumbs(self):
        project = self.get_object()
        if project.status == "completed":
            return [
                ("projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:" + CompanyProjects.list_view_name, )
                 ),
                (f"completed projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:completed_projects" )
                 ),
                (f"{project.title}",
                 reverse(
                     "company_project:" + CompanyProjectsDetailView.detail_view_name,
                     kwargs={'pk': project.id})
                 ),
            ]
        elif project.status == "paused":
            return [
                ("projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:" + CompanyProjects.list_view_name, )
                 ),
                (f"paused projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:paused_projects" )
                 ),
                (f"{project.title}",
                 reverse(
                     "company_project:" + CompanyProjectsDetailView.detail_view_name,
                     kwargs={'pk': project.id})
                 ),
            ]
        else:
            return [
                ("projects", reverse(
                    "company_project:" + CompanyProjects.list_view_name, )
                 ),
                (f"{project.title}",
                 reverse(
                     "company_project:" + CompanyProjectsDetailView.detail_view_name,
                     kwargs={'pk': project.id})
                 ),
            ]
```